# How to order the data with respect to data type

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, data-cleaning, data-analysis

I am having large data set (82 variables) 
Is there any way to arrange data such a way that I have to get all numerical variables firstly then categorical variables so that I can run hypothesis testing or exploratory data analysis(eda) by having loop.

If not is there any way to do eda in simpler manner because I can't check the correlation or chi.square test for each variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let your data frame be `df`. First get the numeric columns:

```
num_col = df.select_dtypes('number').columns
```

Then get the remaining columns.

```
non_num_col = set(df.columns) - set(df.select_dtypes('number').columns)
```

Merge as required.

```
df = pd.concat([df[num_col], df[list(non_num_col)]], axis=1)
```

The columns are now in the desired sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer

Comment: If it worked. Please upvote and Mark as resolved.

Comment: Next time please format your answer properly.